# Game Theory - What is the equilibria?

Tags: game-theory, economics

I think i'm braindead from the amount of time i've stared at this. What is the equilibria in each of the scenarios in this? and preferably the subgame perfect equilibrium? Is there even any, as player 1's choice to bribe can pose different payoffs at the end?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When looking for equilibria, I would start from the end instead of the beginning. What are player 3's optimal choices, assuming player 1 bribes and player 2 accepts? For each of player 3's choices, what are player 2's optimal choice(s)? Working backwards lets you decide what player 1 will do in each situation. (In theory, you're asking "Given any possible sequence of player 1's and player 2's choices, what are player 3's optimal choices?", but in this case there's only one branch of player 1 and 2's choices where 3 gets a choice at all).

Edit: a Nash equilibrium needs to be a *complete contingent plan*. You need to say "P1 bribes, then P2 declines, then P3 doesn't get a choice but if they did they would punish P2" (you could write this as $(B,D,P2)$). If P3 plans to punish P2, there's only one optimal strategy for P2, whereas given P3 plans to punish P2, then there are two optimal strategies for P2. A Nash equilibrium only considers what happens if *one* of the players changes their move, not if (e.g.) P2 changes their move, then P3 changes their response.

Comment: Okay I understand - So assuming P3 aims to maximise their payout - they will choose to punish either P1 or P2. Then assuming P3 punishes, P2 can either decline or accept the bribe - yet they will accept as punishment carries a payoff either the same, or greater than declining the bribe. Therefore, P1 will offer the bribe as it poses the greatest payout, given that P2 Accepts. Does that mean that both types of punishment is nash equilibria, as it doesn't matter to P3 who they punish?

Comment: Not quite - if P3 is planning to punish P1, then P2 can either accept or reject the bribe. In the subgame where P1 bribes, there are three Nash equilibria - either P2 accepts and P3 punishes P1, or P2 rejects and P3 plans to punish P1, or P2 rejects and P3 plans to punish P2. In each of those scenarios, neither P2 nor P3 can benefit by changing their choice, assuming the other player doesn't change theirs.

Comment: There's also a Nash equilibrium where P1 doesn't bribe, P2 plans to reject, and P3 plans to not punish - no player would benefit from changing their choice unless someone else also changes.

Comment: Sweet, thank you for clarifying - I was confusing myself that NE had to have full possibility of occuring